# Uso de AWT en Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Estoy realizando un proyecto en Google App Engine por medio de `java`, mi problema es que necesito hacer una transformación de imágenes, en la cual dibujo una sobre la otra para después utilizar el Datastore y almacenarla.

Todo iba excelente hasta que me di cuenta que Google no le dio soporte a AWT, por lo que la alternativa que dan es usar [Image API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/images/?csw=1) pero esta no me permite la tarea de dibujar una sobre otra como lo podría hacer con Graphics2D, encontre un proyecto [AWT](https://github.com/witwall/appengine-awt) para appengine por medio de JAVA puro pero no pude implementar al 100 por falta de documentacion.

¿Como manejo awt en appengine o en su defecto como dibujo imágenes sobre otras con image API de Google ?

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: Como manejo awt en appengine o en su defecto como dibujo imágenes sobre otras con image API de Google